# Sort SELECT result by pairs of columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

In the following PostgreSQL 8.4.13 table

(where `author` users give grades to `id` users):

```
# \d pref_rep;
                                       Table "public.pref_rep"
  Column   |            Type             |                         Modifiers
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id        | character varying(32)       | not null
 author    | character varying(32)       | not null
 good      | boolean                     |
 fair      | boolean                     |
 nice      | boolean                     |
 about     | character varying(256)      |
 stamp     | timestamp without time zone | default now()
 author_ip | inet                        |
 rep_id    | integer                     | not null default nextval('pref_rep_rep_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "pref_rep_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, author)
Check constraints:
    "pref_rep_check" CHECK (id::text <> author::text)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "pref_rep_author_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES pref_users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "pref_rep_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES pref_users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

how to find faked entries, which have same `id` and same `author_ip`?

I.e. some users register several accounts and then submit bad notes (the `good`, `fair`, `nice` columns above) for other users. But I can still identify them by their `author_ip` addresses.

I'm trying to find them by fetching:

```
# select id, author_ip from pref_rep group by id, author_ip;
           id            |    author_ip
-------------------------+-----------------
 OK490496816466          | 94.230.231.106
 OK360565502458          | 78.106.102.16
 DE25213                 | 178.216.72.185
 OK331482634936          | 95.158.209.5
 VK25785834              | 77.109.20.182
 OK206383671767          | 80.179.90.103
 OK505822972559          | 46.158.46.126
 OK237791033602          | 178.76.216.77
 VK90402803              | 109.68.173.37
 MR16281819401420759860  | 109.252.139.198
 MR5586967138985630915   | 2.93.14.248
 OK341086615664          | 93.77.75.142
 OK446200841566          | 95.59.127.194
```

But I need to sort the above result.

How can I sort it by the number of pairs (id, author_ip) desc please?

Comment: `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`?

Comment: Hmm, yes it does work - but doesn't produce what I hoped...

Comment: Then I think you'll need to clarify what you're hoping to get :)

Comment: Yes sorry, I will prepare a SQL Fiddle in 30 mins and update my question

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, pr.author_ip
from
    pref_rep pr
    inner join
    (
        select author_ip
        from pref_rep
        group by author_ip
        having count(*) > 1
    ) s using(author_ip)
order by 2, 1
```